# Turn off link preview in Mail

Tags: mail.app, preview

In MacOS 13.0 (and 13.0.1) when I paste a link into an email using Mail, it converts the URL into a preview of the web site. How do I turn that off and just have plain links by default? I just want to see the URL I pasted.

Previous version of MacOS did not have this behaviour.

Threads

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254398852
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254346245
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254361654
- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/link-preview-mail.2370469/

Comment: Have you tried looking through Mail's preferences?

Comment: Have you tried pasting with Shift-Command-V (paste as quotation)?

Comment: …or cmd/shift/opt/v [paste & match style]?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Save this plist as /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/Mail.plist and reboot:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RichLinks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Enabled</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How did I find this? I used Hopper on Mail to find likely strings, then worked backwards to find where they were referenced by the code, and then found out that Mail calls _os_feature_enabled_impl("Mail", "RichLinks") to control the feature.

Comment: it worked! thanks so much!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for sharing--finally a way to disable this behaviour altogether!

Comment: Here's a Terminal.app command that does the same: `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/Mail.plist RichLinks -dict-add Enabled -bool NO ; sudo chmod -R o+rX /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags`

Comment: See also the solution by @Nate below: MacOS 14.0 now exposes this as a setting Mail -> Settings… -> Composing -> Add link previews

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that this has changed in 14.0 (yes, I know the OP is asking about 13). The `defaults write` trick no longer works, but! There's now a setting. Uncheck:

Mail -> Settings… -> Composing -> Add link previews

Comment: Thank you to everyone in who posted solutions here, but especially @Nate. The link preview setting exists in iOS 17 also, so hooray.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to paste a link without it being converted to a preview is via Edit -> Add Link (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>). This opens a small dialog box, you paste your link, then hit the OK button.

With the keyboard you use the sequence <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>.
It’s much faster than pasting (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) into Mail, waiting for it to convert the link to a preview, grabbing the mouse, search the small popup handle, clicking once to open the popup, etc.

Just type <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

I also discovered that if you type a space and then paste the URL, it seems to not trigger the Link Preview creation. Then you can delete the space (or leave it). Still annoying, but slightly quicker (maybe?) than <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Yes! I've been doing that for a while. Remembering to put the space in though... aagh. Gets me every time. Call with Apple tomorrow to see if they have a better solution. Will update if they are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your mouse over preview, and a little arrow appear.
Click this arrow to display dropdown menu.
Select *Convert to simple link* (I'm not sure exact translate match)

[image]

The only other way I found to directly past as link is to set `Message format` to `Plain Text` in *Composing* preferences… but inevitably you lose mail formatting

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I didn't want to go back to plain text. I was hoping there was a config setting somewhere to disable it (since it is just new in the latest version)

Comment: @Steve I dig into Mail bin and didn’t find any hidden pref. I point out `RichLink` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The plist answer does not seem to correspond to 13.3:  I have this:

```
<key>RichLinks</key>
<dict>
    <key>DevelopmentPhase</key>
    <string>FeatureComplete</string>
</dict>
```

and have no permission to change it.  Nor is it clear to what it should be changed.

I know all the other workarounds, but like Steve, I just want it OFF. So:

1. what to substitute for the 13.3 setting
2. how to get permission to save the change.

R.

Comment: The "plist answer" is https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457934/489896 right?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal prompt totally worked for me!
In Terminal.app copy paste the below:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/Mail.plist RichLinks -dict-add Enabled -bool NO ; sudo chmod -R o+rX /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags
```

Comment: From the [comment of Thomas Tempelmann](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450339/turn-off-link-preview-in-mail/463095#comment669426_457934)

Answer (score 0):

This works as of MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist AddLinkPreviews -bool false
```

To find other preferences, try:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist
```